# Spring Batch Parallel Job Scaling

Tags: spring, scalability, spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm currently working on a Spring Batch POC and have got a pretty good handle on most of the actual Spring Batch features. I've currently got a program that uses Spring Integration to receive an HttpRequest and use message channels to eventually send the job executions to the job launcher in a queue. What we'd really like to do is implement some kind of "scheduler/load balancer" (not quite sure what to call it) before the job launcher that will look at the currently running worker nodes and the size of the input file and make a decision on how many worker nodes the job should be allowed. We would probably also want to be able to change the amount of worker nodes a job has while it is running to allow more jobs to run.

The idea is that we'd have a server running that could accept many job requests at any time, and a large cluster of machines that jobs will be partitioned onto. We'd like to be able to scale horizontally, so whenever the server isn't busy it can make full use of the hardware, as well as being able to make sure that small jobs don't get constantly blocked by larger jobs.

From my research it seems like we'd have to implement another framework to do this (do GridGain and Hadoop allow this?), but I figured I'd ask to see what people recommended to do something like this, and if there's a way to do it without implementing another large framework.

Sorry if anything is unclear or confusing, I'm just a lowly intern who started learning Spring and Spring Batch last month and I'm far from completely understanding everything, especially this scaling stuff. Just ask and I'll try to clear things up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'spring-batch-integration' project under the spring-batch-admin umbrella project https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch-admin

It has a number of examples of using spring-integration to distribute work to other nodes. IN particular see the chunk and partition packages. Just swap out the spring integration channels with jms channel adapters. By distributing work partitions via JMS, you can scale out the number of worker nodes as needed.

There are a number of threads on this subject in the spring integration forum; search for 'PartitionHandler'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually have a partition handler set up, although it's just distributing the steps to local thread currently. It won't take much to change it to distribute to worker nodes. I'm just not sure how to get the information about how many worker nodes are currently running and how to handle the situation where all the nodes are being used and a new job is put on the queue and I want to decrease the amount of worker nodes a job is using so another job can be run. Is this possible just using JMS and spring-batch-integration? I'm so new to the framework that I don't really know all the capabilities.

Comment: There are a number of tools available to you. You can send control messages to start/stop the inbound endpoint(s) on each node, using an <control-bus/> - eg. "@adapter.stop()". That allows you to control the number of consumers on a particular queue. You can query the JobRepository to get the current state of each partition's step execution status; it won't give you information out of the box as to which node it's running on, but you can add that information to the context.